# For loop, how attribute a value in column by special condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

How to fill a column in df with a specific value, but only by filter condition.

- Only the rows with value "cc" should be attributed
- using as key the column vendorname

Data

```
cw=

vendorname  abb   fff   cc

abb         10    
abb         10    
ffff              1      
cc          
cc          
cc
```

Code

```
cc = 5

for x in cw.vendorname:
    if x == "cc":
        cw['cc'] = f

    else:
        x=x

cw.cc[np.isnan(cw.cc)] = 0
cw.abb[np.isnan(cw.abb)] = 0
cw.ffff[np.isnan(cw.ffff)] = 0
```

Desired output

```
vendorname  abb   fff   cc

abb         10    0      0
abb         10    0      0
ffff        0    1      0
cc          0    0      5
cc          0    0      5
cc          0    0      5
```

Comment: `cw.loc[cw['vendorname'] == 'cc', 'cc'] = 5; cw.fillna(0)`

Comment: @Marat you should probably post it as answer to avoid marking the question as unanswered

Comment: @Marat  thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

cw.loc[cw['vendorname'] == 'cc', 'cc'] = 5; cw.fillna(0)